# Link to changed URL but not rendered component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

We are trying to make a simple website using React-redux. We plan to have a sidebar as follows. When clicking on the "/addcourses"link, the URL changes, but it is not rendering the new component. If I refresh the page, it renders correctly. I read couple of blogs that says not to use Purecomponents. We are not using them. One blog suggests "https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/blocked-updates.md" suggests to pass the location. Not exactly sure how to do that. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.
Here is my sidebar.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

class Sidebar extends Component {



 state = {};
 render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
          <div
            style={{
              padding: "10px",
              width: "40%",
              background: "#f0f0f0"
            }}
          >
            <ul style={{ listStyleType: "none", padding: 0 }}>
              <li>
                <Link to="/dashboard">Home</Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to="/addcourses">Courses</Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to="/payment">Payment</Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default Sidebar;
```

In my App.js I'm doing the following:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <div className="App">
            <Navbar />
            <Route exact path="/" component={LandingPage} />
            {/* <div className="container-fluid"> */}
            <React.Fragment>
              <Route exact path="/verify" component={EmailVerification} />
              <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
              <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
              <Switch>
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
              </Switch>
              <Switch>
                <PrivateRoute
                  exact
                  path="/addcourses"
                  component={AddSwapDeleteWrapper}
                />
              </Switch>
              <Switch>
                <PrivateRoute
                  exact
                  path="/payment"
                  component={Payment}
                />
              </Switch>
              {/* </div> */}
            </React.Fragment>
            <Footer />
          </div>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Try removing the `<Router>` from the sidebar.

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much. You rock!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click on a `<Link>`, the event will be sent to the enclosing `<Router>`, which will trigger a state update and the `<Route>` the link is pointing to gets displayed. If you add two `<Router>`s,  the inner one will process the event, and the outer one won't update. Therefore remove the inner `Router`  to get it working.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.